# How to use reflection to copy complex classes with collections to other classes and different proper names

Tags: c#, reflection, deep-copy

Update: We are familiar with Automapper but we have code that maps our data tables to models and will be easy to add the SqlTable attribute.  And thus we want to be able to do this with simple extensions versus having to do it through Automapper.

Our legacy database has some bad naming practices.  In creating our DateModels, we’ve got rid of a lot of the prefixes and extensions.

What we’re working on is a way to take the EF entities we get back from the database and using reflection copy the property values over into our DataModels.

For a simple class, we have everything work.  The issue we haven’t figured out just yet is how to handle collections.

A sample of our sql tables would be.

Customer Table

```
Cust_Id
Cust_Name
Cust_ProductId -  FK to Product.Id

Product Table
Product_Id
Product_Name
```

Then our data models would be

```
public class CustomerModel : BaseCustomerModel
{
    [SLSqlTable("Cust_Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SLSqlTable("Cust_Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [SLSqlTable("Cust_ProductId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [SLSqlTable("Products")]
    public IList<BaseProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class BaseProductModel 
{
    [SLSqlTable("Product_Id")]        
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [SLSqlTable("Product_Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We’re using the `SLSqlTableAttribute` we created to map the names.

Then from the internet, we’re using the following code to copy the data between properties.  It works fine for everything except our collections right now and that’s what we’re trying to figure out.  We were think, we detect a collection and then some how just recursively call back into `CopyToModelProperties`.

```
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T CopyToModelProperties<T>(this object source) where T : class, new()
{
    T destination = new T();

    Type typeDest = destination.GetType();
    Type typeSrc = source.GetType();

    // Collect all the valid properties to map
    var results = from srcProp in typeSrc.GetProperties()
                  let targetProperty = typeDest.GetProperty(GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(typeDest, srcProp.Name))
                  where srcProp.CanRead
                  && targetProperty != null
                  && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
                  && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
                  select new { sourceProperty = srcProp, targetProperty = targetProperty };

    //map the properties
    foreach (var props in results)
    {
        if (props.targetProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {       
            var _targetType = props.targetProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //    props.sourceProperty.PropertyType.MakeGenericType(_targetType).CopyToModelProperties((dynamic)List<>);
        }
        else
        {
            props.targetProperty.SetValue(destination, props.sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
    }

    return destination;
}

public static string GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(Type model, string sqlName)
{
    string _ret = "";

    var _property = model.GetProperties().Where(w => w.GetCustomAttributes<SLSqlTableAttribute>().Where(w1 => w1.FieldName == sqlName).Any()).FirstOrDefault();

    if(_property != null)
    {
        _ret = _property.Name;
    }

    return _ret;
}
```

Here is a sample of code getting customers with all their products.

```
using (var _dc = new BulkTestEntities())
{
    var _custs = _dc.Customers.Include("Products").ToList();

    foreach(var cust in _custs)
    {
        _resp.Add(cust.CopyToModelProperties<CustomerModel>());
    }
}
```

This works fine and the if condition checking IsGenericType works, we just need to figure out what code goes here that handle the collection of products when getting customer back.

We thought it would be a recursive call back to CopyToModelProperties because Products could have a collection inside it as well and that could have a collection so we don’t want to hard code levels.

So the question is how to take props.sourceProperty from the if condition above and copy a collection of SQL Entities over to a collection of DataModels?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used reflection in a long time but kind of shock something like this wasn't out there or no response.

Digging on the internet, found some code snippets that I pieced together to come up with this. It needs some tweaking but it handles the task we set out to do.  Also, not going to handle all scenarios most likely but good enough for us to start and build on.  Also not all the PITA configuration with something like AutoMapper.  We wrote a program that goes out and gets our sql tables, generates classes and properties and we can easily add our attribute to each property and now all we do is call the functions below to map data.

Code we have to that would use what we came up with.

```
 using (var _dc = new BulkTestEntities())
                {
                    var _custs = _dc.Customers.Include("Products").Include("CustomerType").ToList();


                   // CopyPropertyData.CopyObjectPropertyData(_custs, _resp);
                    //foreach(var cust in _custs)
                    //{
                    //    _resp.Add(cust.CopyToModelProperties<CustomerModel>());
                    //}

                    foreach (var cust in _custs)
                    {
                        CustomerModel _newCust = new CustomerModel();

                        SQLExtensions.CopyToModelProperties(cust, _newCust);
                      //  CopyData.CopyObjectData(cust, _newCust);

                        _resp.Add(_newCust);
                    }
                }
```

Here are the static classes that will handle an IEnumerable and class.

```
     public static void CopyToModelProperties(object source, object target)
            {
                Type _typeTarget = target.GetType();
                Type _typeSrc = source.GetType();

if (_typeSrc.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && _typeSrc.IsGenericType && _typeTarget.IsGenericType)
            {
                // Dynamic allows us to loop through a collection if it's type IEnumerable
                dynamic _sourceList = source;

                foreach (var _source in _sourceList)
                {
                    // Create a temp class of the generic type of the target list
                    object _tempTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(_typeTarget.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

                    //Recursively call to map all child properties
                    CopyToModelProperties(_source, _tempTarget);

                    // Add to target collection passed in
                    target.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(target, new[] { _tempTarget });
                }

            }   
else
                {

                    var results = from srcProp in _typeSrc.GetProperties()
                                  let targetProperty = _typeTarget.GetProperty(GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(_typeTarget, srcProp.Name))
                                  where srcProp.CanRead
                                  && targetProperty != null
                                  && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
                                  && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
                                  //  && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType)
                                  select new { sourceProperty = srcProp, targetProperty = targetProperty };

                    foreach (var prop in results)
                    {
                        if (prop.targetProperty.CanWrite && prop.sourceProperty.CanRead)
                        {
                            object targetValue = prop.targetProperty.GetValue(target, null);
                            object sourceValue = prop.sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);

                            if (sourceValue == null) { continue; }

                            //if (prop.sourceProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                            //    && prop.targetProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                            //    && sourceValue != null)

                            if(prop.sourceProperty.PropertyType.IsClass && prop.targetProperty.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                            {
                                var destinationClass = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.targetProperty.PropertyType);
                                object copyValue = prop.sourceProperty.GetValue(source);

                                CopyToModelProperties(copyValue, destinationClass);

                                prop.targetProperty.SetValue(target, destinationClass);
                            }// See if there is a better way to do this.
                            else if (prop.targetProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && prop.sourceProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                                && prop.targetProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                                && sourceValue != null)
                            {
                                CopyToModelList(source, target, prop.targetProperty, prop.sourceProperty, sourceValue);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // CopySingleData(source, target, prop.targetProperty, prop.sourceProperty, targetValue, sourceValue);
                                prop.targetProperty.SetValue(target, prop.sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
                            }
                        }

                    }            
                }

               // return target;
            }

     private static void CopyToModelList(object source, object target, PropertyInfo piTarget, PropertyInfo piSource, object sourceValue)
            {
                //  int _sourceLength = (int)source.GetType().InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, source, null);

                // First create a generic collection that matches the piTarget being passed in.

                var _listType = typeof(List<>);
props.sourceProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
                var _genericTargetArgs = piTarget.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
                var _concreteTargetType = _listType.MakeGenericType(_genericTargetArgs);
                var _newtargetList = Activator.CreateInstance(_concreteTargetType);

                dynamic _sourceList = piSource.GetValue(source, null);

                foreach (var _source in _sourceList)
                {
                    object _tempTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(piTarget.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

                    CopyToModelProperties(_source, _tempTarget);

                    // here we have to make recursive call to copy data and populate the target list.
                    //_targetList.Add(CopyObjectPropertyData(_source, (dynamic)new object()));
                    _newtargetList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(_newtargetList, new[] { _tempTarget });
                }

                piTarget.SetValue(target, _newtargetList, null);
            }



     public static string GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(Type model, string sqlName)
        {
            string _ret = "";

            var _property = model.GetProperties().Where(w => w.GetCustomAttributes<SLSqlTableAttribute>().Where(w1 => w1.FieldName == sqlName).Any()).FirstOrDefault();

            if(_property != null)
            {
                _ret = _property.Name;
            }

            return _ret;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is such a PITA to edit on this site, creating a new answer that includes caching.  The original posted code performs horribly with 60 records to map.  About 5 seconds.  The new code with caching, 600 records .36 seconds.  In this code we have audit fields and only our mapper can set or change Create audit fields.  It may not apply to you and if so, remove.  All the code below requires is a simple Sql Attribute such as below.  Update that on your model properties if your sql table field names are different than your model property names.  So much easier than Automapper because you don't other type of configuration and if your sql properties match your model properties, then you can use the below to create your own mapper method.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SLSqlTableAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected string _fieldName { get; set; }

    public string FieldName
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldName;
        }
        set
        {
            _fieldName = value;
        }
    }

    public SLSqlTableAttribute(string fieldName)
    {
        FieldName = fieldName;
    }     
}


public class SourceTargetProperties
{
    public PropertyInfo SourceProperty { get; set; }
    public PropertyInfo TargetProperty { get; set; }
}

public static class DataMapper
{
    static Dictionary<string, List<SourceTargetProperties>> _dictTypeProperties = new Dictionary<string, List<SourceTargetProperties>>();

    public static void CopyToSqlProperties(object source, object target, int? userId, DateTimeOffset? modifiedDateTime, bool isInsert)
    {

        Type _typeTarget = target.GetType();
        Type _typeSrc = source.GetType();

        // If we're passed in a collection
        if (_typeSrc.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && _typeSrc.IsGenericType && _typeTarget.IsGenericType)
        {

            dynamic _sourceList = source;

            foreach (var _source in _sourceList)
            {
                object _tempTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(_typeTarget.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

                CopyToModelProperties(_source, _tempTarget);

                // here we have to make recursive call to copy data and populate the target list.
                //_targetList.Add(CopyObjectPropertyData(_source, (dynamic)new object()));
                //  _newtargetList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(_newtargetList, new[] { _tempTarget });
                target.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(target, new[] { _tempTarget });
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // Collect all the valid properties to map

            if (!_dictTypeProperties.ContainsKey(_typeSrc.BaseType.Name))
            {
                _dictTypeProperties.Add(_typeSrc.BaseType.Name, (from srcProp in _typeSrc.GetProperties()
                                                                 let targetProperty = _typeTarget.GetProperty(GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(_typeTarget, srcProp.Name))
                                                                 where srcProp.CanRead
                                                                 && targetProperty != null
                                                                 && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
                                                                 && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
                                                                 //  && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType)
                                                                 select new SourceTargetProperties { SourceProperty = srcProp, TargetProperty = targetProperty }).ToList());
            }
            foreach (var prop in _dictTypeProperties[_typeSrc.BaseType.Name])
            {
                if (prop.TargetProperty.CanWrite && prop.SourceProperty.CanRead)
                {
                    object targetValue = prop.TargetProperty.GetValue(target, null);
                    object sourceValue = prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);

                    if (sourceValue == null) { continue; }

                    //if (prop.sourceProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                    //    && prop.targetProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                    //    && sourceValue != null)

                    if (prop.SourceProperty.PropertyType.IsClass && prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                    {
                        var destinationClass = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType);
                        object copyValue = prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source);

                        CopyToModelProperties(copyValue, destinationClass);

                        prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, destinationClass);
                    }// See if there is a better way to do this.
                    else if (prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && prop.SourceProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && sourceValue != null)
                    {
                        CopyToModelList(source, target, prop.TargetProperty, prop.SourceProperty, sourceValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string _targetPropertyName = prop.TargetProperty.Name;

                        if (modifiedDateTime.HasValue && (_targetPropertyName == "CreatedDateTime" || _targetPropertyName == "LastModifiedDateTime" || _targetPropertyName == "CreatedBy" ||
                         _targetPropertyName == "LastModifiedBy"))
                        {
                            switch (_targetPropertyName)
                            {
                                case "CreatedDateTime":
                                    if (isInsert)
                                    {
                                        prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, modifiedDateTime, null);
                                    }
                                    break;

                                case "CreatedBy":
                                    if (isInsert)
                                    {
                                        prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, userId, null);
                                    }

                                    break;

                                case "LastModifiedDateTime":
                                    prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, modifiedDateTime, null);

                                    break;

                                case "LastModifiedBy":
                                    prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, userId, null);

                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Copy from SQL EF Entities to our Models.
    ///  Models will have the sql table name as a SLSqlAttribute for this to work.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static void CopyToModelProperties(object source, object target)
    {
        Type _typeTarget = target.GetType();
        Type _typeSrc = source.GetType();

        if (_typeSrc.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && _typeSrc.IsGenericType && _typeTarget.IsGenericType)
        {
            // figure out a way to take in collections here instead of having to loop through outside of code.
            //  int _sourceLength = (int)source.GetType().InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, source, null);

            var _listType = typeof(List<>);
            //var _genericArgs = props.sourceProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
            //var _genericTargetArgs = _typeTarget.GetGenericArguments();
            //var _concreteTargetType = _listType.MakeGenericType(_genericTargetArgs);
            //var _newtargetList = Activator.CreateInstance(_concreteTargetType);

            //_newtargetList = piSource.GetValue(source, null);

            //var _genericTargetArgs
            dynamic _sourceList = source;

            //dynamic _sourceList = _typeSrc.GetValue(source, null);
            //    dynamic _targetList = piTarget.GetValue(target, null);

            foreach (var _source in _sourceList)
            {
                object _tempTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(_typeTarget.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

                CopyToModelProperties(_source, _tempTarget);

                // here we have to make recursive call to copy data and populate the target list.
                //_targetList.Add(CopyObjectPropertyData(_source, (dynamic)new object()));
                //  _newtargetList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(_newtargetList, new[] { _tempTarget });
                target.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(target, new[] { _tempTarget });
            }

            //   _typeTarget.SetValue(target, _newtargetList, null);

        }
        else
        {
            // Collect all the valid properties to map

            if (!_dictTypeProperties.ContainsKey(_typeSrc.BaseType.Name))
            {
                _dictTypeProperties.Add(_typeSrc.BaseType.Name, (from srcProp in _typeSrc.GetProperties()
                                                                 let targetProperty = _typeTarget.GetProperty(GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(_typeTarget, srcProp.Name))
                                                                 where srcProp.CanRead
                                                                 && targetProperty != null
                                                                 && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true) != null && !targetProperty.GetSetMethod(true).IsPrivate)
                                                                 && (targetProperty.GetSetMethod().Attributes & MethodAttributes.Static) == 0
                                                                 //  && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProp.PropertyType)
                                                                 select new SourceTargetProperties { SourceProperty = srcProp, TargetProperty = targetProperty }).ToList());
            }

            foreach (var prop in _dictTypeProperties[_typeSrc.BaseType.Name])
            {
                if (prop.TargetProperty.CanWrite && prop.SourceProperty.CanRead)
                {
                    object targetValue = prop.TargetProperty.GetValue(target, null);
                    object sourceValue = prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);

                    if (sourceValue == null) { continue; }

                    //if (prop.sourceProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                    //    && prop.targetProperty.PropertyType.IsArray
                    //    && sourceValue != null)

                    if (prop.SourceProperty.PropertyType.IsClass && prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                    {
                        var destinationClass = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType);
                        object copyValue = prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source);

                        CopyToModelProperties(copyValue, destinationClass);

                        prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, destinationClass);
                    }// See if there is a better way to do this.
                    else if (prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(a => a.Name == "IEnumerable") && prop.SourceProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && prop.TargetProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && sourceValue != null)
                    {
                        CopyToModelList(source, target, prop.TargetProperty, prop.SourceProperty, sourceValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string _targetPropertyName = prop.TargetProperty.Name;
                        prop.TargetProperty.SetValue(target, prop.SourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);

                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // return target;
    }


    public static string GetModelPropertyNameFromSqlAttribute(Type model, string sqlName)
    {
        string _ret = "";

        var _property = model.GetProperties().Where(w => w.GetCustomAttributes<SLSqlTableAttribute>().Where(w1 => w1.FieldName == sqlName).Any()).FirstOrDefault();

        if (_property != null)
        {
            _ret = _property.Name;
        }

        return _ret;
    }



    private static void CopyToModelList(object source, object target, PropertyInfo piTarget, PropertyInfo piSource, object sourceValue)
    {
        //  int _sourceLength = (int)source.GetType().InvokeMember("Count", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, source, null);

        // First create a generic collection that matches the piTarget being passed in.

        var _listType = typeof(List<>);
        //var _genericArgs = props.sourceProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
        var _genericTargetArgs = piTarget.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
        var _concreteTargetType = _listType.MakeGenericType(_genericTargetArgs);
        var _newtargetList = Activator.CreateInstance(_concreteTargetType);

        //_newtargetList = piSource.GetValue(source, null);

        //var _genericTargetArgs
        dynamic _sourceList = piSource.GetValue(source, null);
        //    dynamic _targetList = piTarget.GetValue(target, null);

        foreach (var _source in _sourceList)
        {
            object _tempTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(piTarget.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

            CopyToModelProperties(_source, _tempTarget);

            // here we have to make recursive call to copy data and populate the target list.
            //_targetList.Add(CopyObjectPropertyData(_source, (dynamic)new object()));
            _newtargetList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(_newtargetList, new[] { _tempTarget });
        }

        piTarget.SetValue(target, _newtargetList, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: AM works [without any configuration](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html) if the properties match and it will be much faster than your code.